# Variable from php to realtime graph javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have a realtime graph in JS and i want to take every time the last value from my db.
    JS file is this.

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {


    enter code here

        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });


        $('#cont1').highcharts({
                                            chart: {
                                                type: 'spline',
                                                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                                                marginRight: 10,
                                                events: {
                                                    load: function () {

                                                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                                                        var series = this.series[0];
                                                        var mydata;
                                                        setInterval(function () {

                                                        myData= php file!
                                                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                                                y = myData;
                                                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);                                    
                                                        }, 3000);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            title: {
                                                text: 'AirFlow'
                                            },
                                            xAxis: {
                                                type: 'datetime',
                                                tickPixelInterval: 150
                                            },
                                            yAxis: {
                                                title: {
                                                    text: 'Value'
                                                },
                                                plotLines: [{
                                                    value: 0,
                                                    width: 1,
                                                    color: '#808080'
                                                }]
                                            },
                                            tooltip: {
                                                formatter: function () {
                                                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                                                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                                                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                                                }
                                            },
                                            legend: {
                                                enabled: false
                                            },
                                            exporting: {
                                                enabled: false
                                            },
                                            series: [{
                                                name: 'Random data',
                                                data: (function () {
                                                    // generate an array of random data
                                                    var data = [],
                                                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                                                        i;
                                                        kl = 0
                                                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                                                        data.push({
                                                            x: time + i * 1000,
                                                            y: kl
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                    return data;
                                                }())
                                            }]
                                        });
        });

});

PHP file is :
<?php 
        /* Open connection to  MySQL database. */
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "health_care");

                                                                        /* Check the connection. */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit(); 
                                                                        }
/* Fetch result set from table */
    $data=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT AirFlow FROM health ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");                                                      
                $info=mysqli_fetch_array($data);
        echo $info['AirFlow'];
                                ?>
```

JS file is a real time graph that run in a html file.
    I try to put the php code inside JS file but load it only one time and if new variable come to DB no take it!
    Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make a periodic AJAX request to a PHP file that will provide updated values.

Comment: Can you please help me with the code? I am not good to ajax.